# BTRFS - removing drive by devid instead of path

Tags: filesystems, raid, btrfs

I recently lost a 5 TB drive using btrfs. I had a system freeze (unsure why) while a balance was running. My SMR drive got corrupted. I was able to mount my array degraded and balance my data. However, I now have two devid for the same drive:

```
Total devices 4 FS bytes used 1.43TiB
    devid    1 size 2.73TiB used 1.43TiB path /dev/sdd
    devid    4 size 4.55TiB used 1.31TiB path /dev/sde
    devid    5 size 931.51GiB used 0.00B path /dev/sdc
    devid    6 size 4.55TiB used 121.00GiB path /dev/sde
```

So two /dev/sde. You can see the data draining from devid 4 (which no longer exists) into devid 6. The problem is devid 4 doesn't exist, it's the corrupted drive. And devid 6 is the new one.

When the process is over, how can I delete devid 4? The only way I know is

```
btrfs device delete /dev/sde
```

But that would remove both "devices".

Anyone have any ideas? Honestly, I'm kind of amazed I was able to recover all my data, so btrfs is getting mature, kind of. Wish the documentation followed.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this option didn't exist at the time the question was asked.  However, now the `devid` can be specified to remove the device.  This is now in the man page for `btrfs-device`.  So in your case you would want to run: `btrfs device remove 4 /btrfs/mount/point`

Comment: Thanks. A lot has changed in btrfs between 2015 and 2018. I still appreciate the answer.